# R merge 2 data frames by filtering time variable

Tags: r, datetime, merge, filtering

I continuously measured length of 4 objects (A,B,C,D) across time.

I have 2 data frames i.e. data1 and data2 as shown below...

**data1** contains a measurement data, where length was measured across time.
**data 2** contains categories (A,B,C,D) with their time intervals of measurement.

```
data1 =structure(list(Time = c("9/18/2019 15:30", "9/18/2019 15:31", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:32", "9/18/2019 15:33", "9/18/2019 15:34", "9/18/2019 15:35", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:36", "9/18/2019 15:37", "9/18/2019 15:38", "9/18/2019 15:39", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:40", "9/18/2019 15:41", "9/18/2019 15:42", "9/18/2019 15:43", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:44", "9/18/2019 15:45", "9/18/2019 15:46", "9/18/2019 15:47", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:48", "9/18/2019 15:49", "9/18/2019 15:50", "9/18/2019 15:51", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:52", "9/18/2019 15:53", "9/18/2019 15:54", "9/18/2019 15:55", 
                               "9/18/2019 15:56", "9/18/2019 15:57", "9/18/2019 15:58", "9/18/2019 15:59", 
                               "9/18/2019 16:00", "9/18/2019 16:01", "9/18/2019 16:02", "9/18/2019 16:03", 
                               "9/18/2019 16:04", "9/18/2019 16:05", "9/18/2019 16:06", "9/18/2019 16:07", 
                               "9/18/2019 16:08", "9/18/2019 16:09", "9/18/2019 16:10", "9/18/2019 16:11", 
                               "9/18/2019 16:12", "9/18/2019 16:13", "9/18/2019 16:14", "9/18/2019 16:15", 
                               "9/18/2019 16:16", "9/18/2019 16:17"), length = c(36, 95, 45, 
                                                                                 45, 50, 47, 45, 43, 40, 38, 36, 33, 31, 78, 5, 45, 10, 45, 80, 
                                                                                 116, 151, 186, 222, 257, 292, 328, 45, 454, 57, 197, 203, 209, 
                                                                                 215, 221, 227, 233, 239, 45, 65, 85, 105, 45, 45, 15, 5, 78, 
                                                                                 96, 127)), .Names = c("Time", "length"), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                      cols = structure(list(Time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), length = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "collector"))), .Names = c("Time", "length")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

data1$Time = as.POSIXct(strptime(data1$Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

data2 = structure(list(Class = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), From = c("9/18/2019 15:31", 
                                                       "9/18/2019 15:45", "9/18/2019 15:56", "9/18/2019 16:07"), To = c("9/18/2019 15:40", 
                                                                                                                        "9/18/2019 15:53", "9/18/2019 16:05", "9/18/2019 16:16")), .Names = c("Class", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "From", "To"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(Class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), From = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), To = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector"))), .Names = c("Class", "From", "To")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))


data2$From = as.POSIXct(strptime(data2$From, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
data2$To = as.POSIXct(strptime(data2$To, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

I want to have a merged data frame, where the categories have their length measured within their time intervals (as shown below).

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more details.

p.s The data attached is a toy data. The actual data1 contains 200k rows. I have provided the code for Posixct time conversion.

Comment: Typo in last line? Should `data2$From` be `data2$To`?

Comment: Please check you code, the layout is bad, some parenthesis are missing and the is a typo in the last line

Comment: @Chelmy88 Sorry for the bad layout. I don't know how else to put the data here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with nested `ifelse()` functions:

```
data1$Class=ifelse(data1$Time>data2$From[1] & data1$Time<data2$To[1],"A",
            ifelse(data1$Time>data2$From[2] & data1$Time<data2$To[2],"B",
            ifelse(data1$Time>data2$From[3] & data1$Time<data2$To[3],"C",
            ifelse(data1$Time>data2$From[4] & data1$Time<data2$To[4],"D",NA))))
```

Values for events not falling in any of the 4 category will be `NA`

Comment: It was good solution to use the if-else function. But it's a toy data which has 4 categories (ABCD). Could you suggest some solution which can be applied to many categories?

Comment: I used a for-loop to apply for more categories!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `right_join` from `dplyr` package:

```r
df <- right_join(data2,data1, by = c("From" =  "Time"))
df <- df %>% select(-From)
head(df,11)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   Class To              length
   <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
 1 NA    NA                  36
 2 NA    NA                  95
 3 NA    NA                  45
 4 NA    NA                  45
 5 NA    NA                  50
 6 NA    NA                  47
 7 NA    NA                  45
 8 NA    NA                  43
 9 NA    NA                  40
10 NA    NA                  38
11 A     9/18/2019 15:40     36
```

If you want only the matches, you can use `inner_join` instead of `right_join`

```r
df <- inner_join(data2,data1, by = c("From" =  "Time"))
df <- df %>% select(-From)
df

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Class To              length
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
1 A     9/18/2019 15:40     36
2 B     9/18/2019 15:53    257
3 C     9/18/2019 16:05    233
4 D     9/18/2019 16:16     96
```